# Pandas MultiIndex Vector Setting

Tags: pandas, multi-index

I have a DataFrame with multiindex like this:

```
             0         1         2
 a 0  0.928295  0.828225 -0.612509
   1  1.103340 -0.540640 -0.344500
   2 -1.760918 -1.426488 -0.647610
   3 -0.782976  0.359211  1.601602
   4  0.334406 -0.508752 -0.611212
 b 2  0.717163  0.902514  1.027191
   3  0.296955  1.543040 -1.429113
   4 -0.651468  0.665114  0.949849
 c 0  0.195620 -0.240177  0.745310
   1  1.244997 -0.817949  0.130422
   2  0.288510  1.123550  0.211385
   3 -1.060227  1.739789  2.186224
   4 -0.109178 -1.645732  0.022480
 d 3  0.021789  0.747183  0.614485
   4 -1.074870  0.407974 -0.961013

What I want : array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0])
```

Now I want to generate a zero vector which have the sample length of this DataFrame and only have ones on the first elements of level[1] index.
For example, here the df have a shape of (15, 3). Therefore I want to get a vector with length of 15 and should have 1 at(a, 0), (b, 2), (c, 0), （d, 3) and 0 at other points.
How could I generator an vector like that? (If possible don't loop over get each sub vector and then use np.concatenate()) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC
`duplicated`

```
(~df.index.get_level_values(0).duplicated()).astype(int)
Out[726]: array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0])
```

Or using `groupby` and `head`

```
df.loc[df.groupby(level=0).head(1).index,'New']=1
df.New.fillna(0).values
Out[721]: array([1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.])
```

Comment: The `duplicated` method is nice!

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I have just found a simpler solution. Thank you all the same.

Comment: @Kid hi , you can vote for the answers and accept one of the answers you like

Answer (score 1):

Get the [labels](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.labels.html) of your first multiindex, turn them into a series, then find where they are not equal to the adjacent ones

```
labels = pd.Series(df.index.labels[0])

v = labels.ne(labels.shift()).astype(int).values

>>> v
array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pd.Index(df.labels[0])
Int64Index([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3], dtype='int64')
res = pd.Index(df.labels[0]).duplicated(keep='first')
array([False,  True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True, False,
       True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True])
```

Mulitindex has an attribute labels to indicate postion.
Which has the same meaning of the requirement.